# Passing pointers to structs through functions

Tags: c

Hi could you please help for an error in C?
I have two source files and a header.
The one source is the main and the other source is full of functions and the header contains the functions declarations
This is the main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "fundeclarationheader.h"


int main() {
InfoSessionPtr  MySession=NULL;
My Session = Session;
function(MySession->Tab);

return 0;
}
```

and this is the other source file

```
InfoSessionPtr Session;
TabNodePtr Tab;

struct InfoSession {
TabNodePtr FirstTab;
TabNodePtr LastTab;
TabNodePtr CurrTab;
TabNodePtr AuxTab;
char*     OpeningAddress;
};

struct TabNode {
TabNodePtr PrevTab, NextTab;
SiteNodePtr FirstSite;
SiteNodePtr CurrSite;
};

struct SiteNode{
SiteNodePtr PrevSite, NextSite;
TabNodePtr UpTab;
char *Address;
};

void function(TabNodePtr CurrTab){
 //body of function
}
```

and now this is the header

```
typedef struct InfoSession *InfoSessionPtr;
typedef struct TabNode *TabNodePtr;
typedef struct SiteNode *SiteNodePtr;
void function(TabNodePtr);
```

Well the problem here is that when trying to call the "function" in main I get a message with GCC : dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Comment: At least this, `My Session = Session;` appears to be invalid.

Comment: **Never ever** `typedef` data pointers!

Answer (score 2):

How can the compiler know what an InfoSession struct contains when it compiles main.c? You need to put the struct definition in the header file, and then #include it in both source files.

Comment: Or else don't try to declare instances or access instances' members.  You can implement opaque types by declaring `struct`s without providing their bodies, as the OP's code does, but then you can't do anything with them that requires knowing their members and layout.  Mainly, you can store the pointers and pass them around, including to functions to which maybe they *aren't* opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine you header and source file.

Struct need to be declared in header, before you do typedef. So If you can combine both this should be working fine.

Comment: Cant do that as it is for an excercise witch require encapsulation
In addition if I delete the function call it works smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Cant merge them as it is for an excercise witch require encapsulation In addition if I delete the function call it works smoothly

In addition the

```
MySession = Session
```

line isnt correct as I changed the code in order to demonstrate it to u 
thats why in the real propram I use a function which exists in the other source file that returns the Session so everything is smooth
the only problem is the one with the "function" call